# Scheme member? function

Tags: scheme

I created the procedure `member?` in Scheme as follows:

```
(define member?
    (lambda (x los)
        (cond
            ((null? los) #f)
            ((if (eq? x (car los)) #t (member? x (cdr los)))))))
```

I have made a couple of test cases that all pass, except for `(member? 'a '(b c d))` which returns nothing (or `#<void>` to be exact), and I am wondering why.

Rudimentary debugging of the code (adding `(display los)` on the second line) indicates that the procedure does recursively run through the list until it becomes a null list `'()` but does not get caught by `((null? los) #f)`

Comment: look at your `if`, which is already inside a `cond`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to look up how to use `cond`:

```
(define member?
  (lambda (x los)
    (cond
      ((null? los) #f)
      ((eq? x (car los)) #t)
      (else (member? x (cdr los))))))
```

Comment: Just figured that out and was seconds from typing out the same exact answer! I tried that earlier and I think I added an extra parenthesis behind `else`.

Answer (score 1):

An predicate only term in a `cond` will evaluate to the result if the predicate evaluates to a true value, but not if it is the false value `#f`. then it falls through to the next term.

If you have a `if` or `cond` where not all cases are handled the implementation have choice of outcome:

```
(let ((b 4))
  (cond
    ((< b 2) 'less-than-2)
    ((zero? b) 'zero)))
; ==> "https://youtu.be/wd4Oxk11PA0?t=17s"
```

Since R6RS the standard urges implementers to have an object to represent the underspecified value but Scheme imlementations doesn't need to follow these. Eg. MIT Scheme returns the old value rather than the undefined value from `set!`:

```
(define test 10)
(set! test 20)
; ==> 10 (returns the old binding)
```